# Nuget "Older to New" Update Failed

Tags: nuget

I want to update project for Asp.NET Web Api 2.2 (My project is Web Api 1.0). But Nuget doesn't update all package and i didn't find this problem's solve.

Can you help me for this problem ?

Failed Text:

> Updating 'Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Core 4.0.30506.0' to 'Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Core 5.2.0' failed. Unable to find a version of 'Strathweb.CacheOutput' that is compatible with 'Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Core 5.2.0'.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the current build of [Strathweb.CacheOutput](http://www.nuget.org/packages/strathweb.cacheoutput) (0.5.0) package is fixed to WebApi 4.0.30506.

You have 2 options:

- Contact the package owner and ask them to allow the package to work with newer versions of WebApi
- Use the command line for NuGet in Visual Studio to force the package update by specifying the [`-IgnoreDependencies`](http://docs.nuget.org/docs/reference/package-manager-console-powershell-reference#Update-Package) argument

Either way, you will need a binding redirect for Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Core 4.0.30506.0 -> 5.2.0, depending on which option you use, NuGet may add this to your web.config for you.